# Sort descending response from api

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sort object array according to the points. In response, I am getting as shown in below image.

[image]

I want it to start from highest `points_earned` to lowest. For now it start with 50 and end with 1000. I want it to be start from 1000 and end with 50.

I have tried with the following code but doesn't seem working. Please help.

```
var homes = response.response.conversion_summary_stats;
console.log(homes);
homes.sort(function(a,b) { return a.points_earned.valueOf() < b.points_earned.valueOf();});
console.log(homes);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Subtract the values:**

*This approach sorts in ascending direction*

```
homes.sort(function(a,b) { return a.points_earned - b.points_earned;});
```

*This approach sorts in descending direction*

```
homes.sort(function(a,b) { return b.points_earned - a.points_earned;});
```

Comment: It seems working but instead of `a-b`, `b-a` seems working for descending order. Thank you